# Посоветуйте урок, чтобы добиться такого результата

Tags: веб-программирование, дизайн

Решил создать рыболовный интернет-магазин, хочу сделать задний фон такого плана, как на этом изображении. Конкретно интересует вода, рыба не нужна.

[image]

Посоветуйте как можно добиться такого результата. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Урок:))

1. Находите в гугле картинку звездное небо (или пузырьки) в выском разрешении (Инструменты, Разрешение, Больше чем:).
2. Находите там же красивую воду (я тунул по русскому слову "вода" и размеры больше 2МП).
3. Методом "волшебной палочки" и "ластика" с низкой жесткостью делается красивый переход.
4. Можно добавить насыщенности или контраста на ваш вкус.

Собсвенно, если рыба, брызги от нее и тень не нужны... то этого должно хватить.

1. На воду можно кинуть редактирование\трансформация\перспектива. Это даст вам ощущения ухода вглубь.

Собственно ваша рыба в разрешении по-больше.

http://livedemo00.template-help.com/joomla_33451/images/stories/main_pic3.jpg

**Обновление**

http://basik.ru/images/water_wallpapers_53/011_wallpaper.jpg

http://wallpampers.ru/wallpapers/21638/Clear%20Water.jpg

http://fotobg.ru/upload/img1352024417.jpg

http://www.nastol.com.ua/images/201210/nastol.com.ua_33510.jpg

http://wallpaper.goodfon.ru/image/293294-1920x1200.jpg

http://web-mirror.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/water20.jpg (нужно будет повернуть на 180)

http://oformi.net/uploads/gallery/main/31/wallpapers_30.jpg (слегка не в тему, но прикольно)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Может еще дадите ссылку на красивую воду? = ))

Comment: А если еще припляшем к элементу в котором будет прописан этот рисунок в качестве background - свойсто *background-size: cover;* Вообще будет красота)